# .net data reader in background worker

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, asynchronous

I am trying to query a DB in a background worker in order for my form not to be frozen while the query is being processed. However since I moved to this solution, the data reader only retrieves the first result of the query instead of 400.000+ ...

```
Public Class Form5
    Public con As OdbcConnection = Form1.con
    Public cmd As New OdbcCommand
    Public dr As OdbcDataReader

    Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
    Public Delegate Sub PictureVisibilityDelegate(ByVal visibility As 
    Boolean)
    Dim ChangePictureVisibility As PictureVisibilityDelegate

    Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
        MyBase.Load
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
        ChangePictureVisibility = AddressOf ChangeVisibility

        bw.RunWorkerAsync()

    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeVisibility(ByVal visibility As Boolean)
        PictureLoader.Visible = visibility
        PictureLoader.SendToBack()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Me.Invoke(ChangePictureVisibility, True)

        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT xxx, xxx, xxx from xxx.xxx where xxx.xxx      
        = """ & dt1.Rows(Form1.line).Item(4) & """"
        cmd = New OdbcCommand(SQL, con)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()
           DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() 
           {dr(0).ToString,dr(1).ToString & " %", dr(2).ToString})
        End While

     End Sub

    Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As                 
    RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        Me.Invoke(ChangePictureVisibility, False)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I really can't wrap my head around that and couldn't find any similar problem on the net, so any comment would be really appreciated...

Comment: I feel your pain trying to do asynchronous programming in VB.NET

Comment: Never ever do UI stuff in the `DoWork` event handler. This line: `DataGridView1.Rows.Add(...)` *will* cause you pain. I don´t know if it fixes your problem but I highly recommend to change it.

Comment: Additionally if you have any chance to change it: Have a look at the [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) pattern. Imho it´s the defacto standard in .NET >= 4.5 to develop asynchronous operations. It can easily replace any Backgroundworker solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Populate a `DataTable` in your `DoWork` event handler and assign that to `e.Result`.  Get it back from `e.Result` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler and bind it to your grid.

The `DoWork` event handler is where you do the background work. Anything to do with the UI is NOT background work. The `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler is executed on the UI thread, so that's where you update the UI once the background work is done.

In the `DoWork` event handler:

```
Dim table As New DataTable

table.Load(dr)
e.Result = table
```

In the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = e.Result
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, it works like a charm! I still don't fully understand the weird behavior of outputting the first result and stopping, but now it's very clear that I shouldn't do anything UI related in the other thread. Thanks again!

Comment: That's the thing: it's hard to predict exactly what will happen when you access controls across thread boundaries. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. There's obviously logic to it at a low level but, at a high level, it just seems unpredictable. Avoid and you avoid those issues.